# Doctrine 2 get related entities in PreFlush

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, lifecycle

There are following entities: `Zone`, `ZoneRecord`

`ZoneRecord` has a Method `validate()` to validate against all other `ZoneRecord`'s of related `Zone`.

Now I want to check / validate each `ZoneRecord` (the ones which are saved already **plus** the ones which are added by `Zone->addRecord(ZoneRecord)` on runtime) which is related to the `Zone` if `Zone` gets saved.

Right now I have a `PreFlush` Lifecyclecallback `ZoneRecord->validate` where I trigger `this->getZone->getRecords()`: **this methods gives me only the already saved entities which are in db**.

How can I get ALL related Entities of `Zone` (the saved from DB and the dynamicly added)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem seems to be in Doctrine internal.
I use [InheritanceType "JOINED"](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance).

The annotation in `Zone` looks like:

```
/**
 * @var ZoneRecord[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ZoneRecord", mappedBy="zone", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $records;

/**
 * @var ZoneRecordA[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ZoneRecordA", mappedBy="zone", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $recordsa;
```

The annotation from `ZoneRecord`:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="zonerecords")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *  "A" = "Application\Entity\ZoneRecordA"
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class ZoneRecord
```

The annotation from `ZoneRecordA`:

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="zonerecords_a")
 *
 */
class ZoneRecordA extends ZoneRecord
```

If I add or remove a `ZoneRecord` from `Zone` via `Zone->addRecordA(ZoneRecord)` / `Zone->removeRecordA(ZoneRecord)` it will only be removed from the `protected $recordsa;` stack. The `protected $records;` will be untouched until the entity is successfully flushed and reloaded.

It seems that Doctrine does internal differ between `ZoneRecord` and `ZoneRecordA` although they are marked as JOINED and `ZoneRecordA` extends `ZoneRecord`.

This is especially a problem if you want to delete Records - right now I use both delete Methods (`Zone->removeRecord(ZoneRecordA)` and `Zone->removeRecordA(ZoneRecordA)`) to be sure the Entity is removed from the EntityManager.

This strange behaviour also occurs if you add entitys to `Zone` via `addRecord()` or `addRecordA()`, they are used as different collections until they are flushed and reloaded.